# How to traverse employee manager relationship?

Tags: python, loops, recursion

Given a list of employee id and manager id pairs, and given a manager id print/return the manager hierarchy, starting at that manager. For example, given `(manager_id, employee_id)` as `[(1,3), (2,3), (3,4)]` and `manager_id 4`, return `{4:[3], 3:[1,2]}`.

Here is my code so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

str = [(1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (5,4), (10,4), (6,2)]
hierarchy  = defaultdict(list)

def find_emp(mgr_id):
    for i in str:
        if mgr_id in i:
            if i[0] != mgr_id:
                hierarchy[mgr_id].append(i[0])
        else:
            continue

for val in hierarchy:
    for item in hierarchy[val]:
        print(item)
        find_emp(item)


print(find_emp(4))
```

My code is failing as it exceeds max recursion depth. Can someone help me in identifying the broken piece in my logic?

Comment: Do you get an error or the program just crash ?

Comment: is your indentation in the code above correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error log would help a ton...

But I am suspecting that your code is actually failing in the inner most if statement within the def find_emp(mgr_id):

You can't iterate through a tuple within a list like that, it would have to be something like this:

```
     for i in str:
     ...
     if i[mgr_id][0] != mgr_id:
        hierarchy[mgr_id].append(i[mgr_id][0])
```

if you can fix that first, and maybe post an image of the actual error, that would give a clearer picture as to what and where it's halting.